# Converting a string of comma separated numbers into numbers

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mathjs

I am trying get a list of comma separated numbers to process in math.js library (https://github.com/josdejong/mathjs/blob/master/docs/functions.md) in Node.js.

While I got the list list of numbers like "2,4,5" and did a comma split to store in an array. The library refused to process my array using it's math.add() function. It needs individual integers to process. I could use the function with array[0],array[1] but I want to provide all the integers at once using a single variable.

```
exports.add = function(req, res) {
    var v = req.params.v;
    var array = v.split(",");
    var intarray = [];
    for(var i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
        intarray[i] = +array[i];
    }
    var result = math.add(intarray);
    res.end(result.toString());
}
```

Comment: Do you have any console errors? Your [array conversion code works fine](http://jsfiddle.net/aFt55/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update**: You've said you want to call `math.add` once, with all the values, but I don't think it supports doing that. Both the doc on the function and [the source](https://github.com/josdejong/mathjs/blob/master/lib/function/arithmetic/add.js) say it only supports two arguments, not an unlimited series of them.

So you can't do it all at once; you'd be better off doing it as you parse:

```
exports.add = function(req, res) {
    var v = req.params.v;
    var array = v.split(",");
    var result = 0;
    for(var i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
        result = math.add(result, +array[i]);
    }
    res.end(result.toString());
}
```

Or in an ES5-enabled (or a shimmed) environment:

```
exports.add = function(req, res) {
    var result = 0;
    req.params.v.split(",").forEach(function(val) {
        result = math.add(result, val);
    });
    res.end(result.toString());
}
```

**But** since you know these are JavaScript numbers, I don't see any reason to use `math.add` at all. It just adds them together, allowing for various types. But you know the type of these numbers, so you're not getting anything except overhead by calling it.

Original answer before I went looking:

---

> It needs individual integers to process. I could use the function with array[0],array[1] but I want to provide all the integers at once using a single variable.

If `math.add` supports a series of discrete arguments, you can use your array like this:

```
var result = math.add.apply(math, intarray);
```

`apply` calls the function that you call it on using the first argument you give it as the `this` value within the call, and the contents of the array you give as the second argument as the individual arguments for the function.

It's easier to understand with an example:

```
/// A function accepting three formal arguments
function foo(a, b, c) {
    console.log("a = " + a);
    console.log("b = " + b);
    console.log("c = " + c);
}

// An array with 1, 2, 3 in it
var a = [1, 2, 3];

// Call `foo`, passing in the array to use as the discrete arguments
foo.apply(undefined, a);
```

That outputs:

```
a = 1
b = 2
c = 3
```

In that example, I didn't need `this` to be anything in particular within the call to `foo`, so I used `undefined`. When calling an object's method (`math.add`, for instance), it's best to use the object, as that's what `this` would normally be within the call.

Comment: @Crowder you are my superstar :)

Comment: Yea, I just checked, I couldn't add more than two numbers. Actually my sole purpose is not to just add numbers, I know javascript itself can do basic arithmetic operations, I wanted to use more advanced functions of math.js later on.

Comment: @user2714639: Ah, gotcha. Glad that helped.

Answer (score 1):

math.js now supports the function `sum`, counting an array or matrix with values:

```
var math = mathjs();

var result = math.sum([2,4,5]);
console.log(result); // 11
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Array.prototype.reduce`

```
var result = intarray.reduce(function(prev, curr) { return math.add(prev, curr); }, 0);
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce for details on Array Reduce.

Comment: I'm not seeing why this is downvoted. Unless there's a requirement we don't know about (some reason that we have to call `math.add` only once, with all the numbers), this is a reasonable approach on an ES5-enabled (or shimmed) system.

Comment: And having looked it up, you *can't* call `math.add` with more than two args (or rather, you can, but it won't use them). So this is a reasonable approach.